# catboost установка

Tags: python, linux, catboost

При установке этой библиотеки есть несколько вариантов, я выбрал который Build from source on Linux. Порядок действия там такой:

1. должна быть libc6-dev
2. Clone the repository
3. Зайти в     catboost/catboost/python-package/catboost 
   и выполнить код типа 
   `../../../ya make -r -DUSE_ARCADIA_PYTHON=no -DOS_SDK=local
   -DPYTHON_CONFIG=<path to the required python-config> [optional 
   parameters]`

У меня проблемы с ya make. Пишут что это яндексовская утилита. 
Файлик ya.make действительно лежит почти в каждой папке и содержит исполняемый код. Что с точкой его написать, что без - выдаётся ответ `команда не найдена`. Я смотрел обсуждение этой темы и выложенные логи - люди пишут "ya make".

Элементарный вопрос, но залипaю уже 2е сутки. Поделитесь пожалуйста опытом.

Answer (score 1):

Файлы ya.make - это не исполняемые файлы, это текстовые файлы, описывающие, как собирать проект. А утилита ya лежит не в каждой папке, а только в одном месте. Путь к ней нужно указать так ../../../ya, если вы находитесь в папке catboost/catboost/python-package/catboost
make при этом будет являться параметром команды запуска утилиты ya, поэтому писать нужно через пробел, а не через точку. Проще всего скопировать команду сборки из инструкции.

Однако наиболее удобный способ установки - это "pip install catboost", советую использовать именно его.